# Make a dictionary using tkinter, GUI

Tags: python, dictionary, input, tkinter

I want to make a dictionary by using a GUI, I was thinking of making two entries, one for the object and the other for the key. And I want to make a button that execute the information and add it to the empty dictionary.

```
from tkinter import *

fL = {}

def commando(fL):
    fL.update({x:int(y)})


root = Tk()
root.title("Spam Words")

label_1 = Label(root, text="Say a word: ", bg="#333333", fg="white")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Give it a value, 1-10:", bg="#333333", fg="white")
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=x)
entry_2 = Entry(root, textvariable=y)

label_1.grid(row=1)
label_2.grid(row=3)

entry_1.grid(row=2, column=0)
entry_2.grid(row=4, column=0)

but = Button(root, text="Execute", bg="#333333", fg="white", command=commando)
but.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to use that dictionary later in my main program. You see if it would be a function, I would just go in IDLE and do..

```
 def forbiddenOrd():

        fL = {}
        uppdate = True
        while uppdate:
            x = input('Object')
            y = input('Key')
            if x == 'Klar':
                break
            else:
                fL.update({x:int(y)})
        return fL
```

And then just use the function further on in my program 
Any suggestions?
I appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to achieving what you want.  There are a few modifications that need to be made.  First, lets start with the entry boxes `entry_1` and `entry_2`.  Using a `text variable` like you did is a good approach; however I did not see them defined, so here they are:

```
x = StringVar()
y = StringVar()
```

Next, we need to change how you call the `commando` function and what parameters you pass though it.  I want to pass the `x` and `y` values though, but I can't do this by just using something like `command=commando(x.get(), y.get())`, I need to use `lambda` as follows:

```
but = Button(root, text="Execute", bg="#333333", fg="white", command=lambda :commando(x.get(), y.get()))
```

Now why did I pass the values `x` and `y` as `x.get()` and `y.get()`?  In order to get the values from a tkinter variable such as `x` and `y`, we need to use `.get()`.

Finally, let's fix the `commando` function.  You cannot use it as you did with `fL` being the parameter.  This is because any parameter you set there becomes a private variable to that function even if it appears elsewhere in you code.  In other words, defining a function as `def commando(fL):` will prevent the `fL` dictionary outside the function from being assessed within `commando`.  How do you fix this?  Use different parameters.  Since we are passing `x` and `y` into the function, let's use those as parameter names.  This is how our function looks now:

```
def commando(x, y):
    fL.update({x:int(y)})
```

This will create new items in your dictionary.  Here is the completed code:

```
from tkinter import *

fL = {}

def commando(x, y):
    fL.update({x:int(y)})  # Please note that these x and y vars are private to this function.  They are not the x and y vars as defined below.
    print(fL)

root = Tk()
root.title("Spam Words")

x = StringVar()  # Creating the variables that will get the user's input.
y = StringVar()

label_1 = Label(root, text="Say a word: ", bg="#333333", fg="white")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Give it a value, 1-10:", bg="#333333", fg="white")
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=x)
entry_2 = Entry(root, textvariable=y)

label_1.grid(row=1)
label_2.grid(row=3)

entry_1.grid(row=2, column=0)
entry_2.grid(row=4, column=0)

but = Button(root, text="Execute", bg="#333333", fg="white", command=lambda :commando(x.get(), y.get()))  # Note the use of lambda and the x and y variables.
but.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I understand! Camon, thank you so much! Yet, I have a question before we close this page. Why did you put lambda? What is so special with it? I mean I have watched some videos at YouTube, but why do we use it in this case? We have defined a fucntion but yet we stil use lambda with it?

Comment: @MajdJamal Using `lambda` in tkinter apps (and other GUI tools) is particularly useful if you need to pass arguments into a function.  If you used something like `command=function(param1, param2)`, as soon as the app launches, that command is run immediately (despite there being no button press from the user).  Using `lambda` in the `command=`, the function will only run with our given parameters when the button is pressed.  I recommend you try removing lambda and see what happens.  Hopefully that clears things up a bit.